# MySQL performance: many rows and columns (MyISAM)

Tags: mysql, optimization, split

Since I'm still in the beginning of my site design I figured now's a good time to ask this.

I know that one of the ways to optimize MySQL queries is to split your rows into seperate tables, however, that does have a few comfort issues.

What I'm considering is this: would querying a table consisting of around `1'000'000` rows and `150` columns using excellently designed indexes and getting only the needed columns from each query result in a *much* higher server load than splittiing the table into multiple ones, resulting in less collumns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Big blob tables are a anti-pattern, never use them.

Normalized tables will run much much faster than a single blob.
InnoDB is optimized for many small tables that need to be joined.

Using a normalized table will save you many headaches besides:

1. Your data will be smaller, so more of it fits in memory.
2. You only store data in one place, so it cannot end up with inconsistent data.
3. MySQL only allows you to use one index per select per table, multiple tables means you get to use more indexes and get more speed.
4. Triggers on tables execute much faster.
5. Normalized tables are easier to maintain.
6. You have less indexes per table, so inserts are faster.
7. Indexes are smaller (fewer rows) and narrows (less columns) and will run much faster as a result.

Comment: I haven't really thought of those points. Thank you, I'll be sure to consider it.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is static, you can pack the tables for greater efficiency. Here is the [page in the reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/myisampack.html)

Comment: Unfortunately around 90-95% of it will be dynamic.